# What are these pants designs called?

Tags: clothing, pattern-drafting

If you watch the opening of this video, you’ll see a child actor riding a donkey. He is wearing a white henley shirt and some type of overall pants with a single strap.

https://youtu.be/ArZK6aneeKg

What would these pants be called?

[image: Boy on horse in said trousers]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's called a one shoulder overall. See the links below for vendors selling something similar to what this boy is wearing.

https://www.evisu.com/us/splash-embroidered-one-shoulder-overalls-2esgnw1js285rx.html

https://riceforlunch.com/home/product/asymmetrical-one-shoulder-overalls/

Comment: I'm not sure if the straps are similar, since the ones in your answer are obviously based on overalls and have a larger area at the base, but these are certainly very close and will likely help the OP.